# Inserting values in a Table in sql server options

Tags: t-sql

Suppose I have a table student having two not nullable columns `a` & `b` of type integer and two nullable columns `c` & `d` of type integer ..

When I write a query `Insert into student (a,b) values (1,2)` it works.

But when I write a query `Insert into student Select 1,2`

that doesn't work. My thought is that it should work as I have two not nullable columns and I am providing two input values which should go automatically into the not null able columns.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not specify the columns to be inserted into it is assumed as insert into all columns. That means if the number of columns in your `SELECT` is different from that in the table there will be an error of column count mismatch.

Note that an exception to this is `IDENTITY` columns where you are not supposed to insert data yourself, or columns which have a default value defined.

You can refer to the [documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) to get a better idea.